# Name of a href tag

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm a complete newbie with regular expressions and I feel bad about it now, when I need some serious advice on how to extract a link name out of an ahref tag, ie.

```
<a href="article.html?id=1999874">This article is cool</a>
```

and I would need to extract "This article is cool", minding that "article.html?id=" CANNOT be avoided. I tried it with

```
preg_match_all('/<a href="article.html?id=([0-9])">([^<]*)<\/a>/', $webpage, $match);
```

and what I get back is just

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )
```

Thanks for any valuable advice!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1415038

Comment: `[0-9]+` because the id contains multiple digits, also escape `?`

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Onetrickpony got to the heart of what's wrong with your regex: your numeric ID has multiple digits, but your regex only matches a single digit.

There are some other things I'm going to throw out there for your consideration.  First, if there are other attributes in your `<a>` tag, your regex will fail.  For example, if there's a `target="_blank"` attribute, it will mess up your regex.  Fortunately, there's an easy way around that:

```
preg_match_all('/<a .*?href="article\.html\?id=([0-9]+)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/',
    $webpage, $match);
```

Essentially, I just padded the `href` attribute with `.*?`.  The question mark makes the matches *lazy* (instead of the default of *greedy*), which will prevent it from consuming more than you want.  I also replaced your `[^<]` with a lazy match, because I generally find it a little cleaner.

UPDATE: As demonking correctly pointed out, the period and question mark in `article.html?id=` need to be escaped.  The period doesn't matter so much, except that leaving it in there would match `article_html` or anything else, which is probably not a concern.  However, not escaping the question mark is trouble.  It makes the `l` in `html` optional, but then there's nothing to actually match the question mark, which is probably why my uncorrected solution was failing.  Thanks, demonking!

Comment: Than you for your response, but still, what I receive back with $match is: Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )

Comment: The Problem here is, that you have to escape the ? and .(dot) because this are regex elements

Comment: Oh, you're right about the ?.  Escaping the dot is not as important, but you're technically correct.  Good call, demonking.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be look something like this:

```
<a(.+)?href="article\.html\?id=([0-9]+?)">(.+)?<\/a>
```

The Problem would be, if someone would include some classes or id's to your a href.
Then the regex wouldn't work properly.

Example:

```
<?php

$str = '<a href="article.html?id=1999874">This article is cool</a>';

$matches = array();

preg_match_all('/<a.?href="article\.html\?id=([0-9]+?)">(.+)?<\/a>/',$str,$matches);

var_dump($matches);


?>
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(58) "<a href="article.html?id=1999874">This article is cool</a>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "1999874"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(20) "This article is cool"
  }
}
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't use `<a.?href` because that could match someting like `<ahref` or `<a-href`...not sure why you would ever see those in HTML, but you never know.  I prefer `<a .*?href` because it makes sure it's an a tag and not something funky.  Otherwise good solution.